# Content is not allowed in prolog error in Gradle

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

In my project i am using apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar to access Http Components but when i sync Gradle it shows error,

Gradle Error:

```
 F:\softwares backup\ecllipse\workspace\Test\app\src\main\res\lib\apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar 
 Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
 > F:\softwares backup\ecllipse\workspace\Test\app\src\main\res\lib\apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
 Information:BUILD FAILED
```

My Gradle File:

```
 dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
compile files('src/main/res/lib/org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient_4.5.2.jar')
compile files('src/main/res/lib/apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar')
 }
 android{
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
}
```

Please guide me to clear this issue.